# Story Identification: Devouring Darkness

Tags: story-identification

So I started reading a novel somewhere around 20 years ago and I'm very fuzzy on the details.
What I remember is it involved a cloud of darkness just kind of rolling over and consuming everything it happened to touch. It was quite creepy and my then 12(ish) year old self wasn't capable of appreciating nightmare fuel and abandoned ship. (Did the same thing with the first of Alten's Meg books...)

I'm fairly certain I'm -not- thinking of Asimov's Nightfall... That seems far less... creepifying than I remember. Also if memory serves (sometimes it doesn't) it was set on Earth; and I'm pretty sure a detail like six suns would habe stood out. The part that -is- still etched into my memory is a scene where this dark cloud of maybe aliens consumes a small farmhouse.

Comment: Earth is invaded by cloud-like aliens from Mars in Olaf Stapledon's *Last and First Men*, but the Martian invasion is only one chapter in a long story, and it's not told in a "creepifying" style, so I'm pretty sure that's not the book you remember. Can you describe in more detail the farmhouse scene that's etched in your memory?

Comment: Not aliens, but I believe an all-consuming darkness factors heavily into the Neverending Story?

Answer (score 2):

It makes me think of the french book "La nuit est morte" (the night is dead), from Paul Bera. I don't know if it has ever been translated.

http://www.livrenpoche.com/la-nuit-est-morte-e30390.html

"Deux thèmes dans ce roman.
Celui des. Humains condamnés à une existence de sauvages sur une planète devenue hostile à cause de la Nuit Vivante, qui a surgi de quelque Univers inconnu.
Celui des couples : l'un sauvage, l'autre hautement " civilisé qui, par curiosité, vont changer de partenaire sur un monde où la Nuit Vivante cherche à absorber toute leur énergie vitale afin de regagner son Univers d'origine.
Il faudra bien que certains meurent pour ouvrir aux autres la voie de la liberté en supprimant la Nuit Vivante..."

To sum up, a giant "snake of darkness" attacks an expedition by sending energy eating darkness over it.

Two couples of humans are trying to fight it.